# why do I receive trap 14 message with dynamic array saved in stack

Tags: c, xv6

I am practicing reading a txt file by each char and saving into dynamic array.  I am not using standard library as I practicing in XV6 operating environment.

However, I received the error message "pid 4 trap 14 err 7 on cpu" and I still have no clue why I received this. In order to avoid any memory allocation problem I created dynamic array large enough in stack.

my text file only 5 lines with 5 letters like this.

```
exam1  
exam2  
exam3  
exam4
```

```
#include "types.h"
#include "stat.h"
#include "user.h"

char c;

void testing(int fd, char* name)
{
    int n, i, count = 0, reset = 0;
    char placeholder[225][225];
    while ((n = read(fd, &c, 1)) > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (c == '\n') {
                placeholder[count][reset++] = c;
                placeholder[count][reset++] = '\0';
                reset = 0;
                count++;
            }
            else {
                printf(1, "c value: %c \n", c); //testing purpose
                placeholder[count][reset] = c;
                reset++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (n < 0) {
        printf(1, "trial: read error\n");
        exit();
    }

    printf(1, "\n");
    int l;
    for (l = 0; l < sizeof(placeholder); l++) {
        printf(1, "placeholder[0]%s: %c \n", l, placeholder[0][l]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What should `printf(1, "\n");` do? What is the `1` as first parameter?

Comment: 1 as first parameter only take a character as it reads. printf statement is just for me. I do not think that's important issue.

Comment: Okay, you have your own `printf` implementation, which is not compatible with the standard `printf` version. Another problem is `for (l = 0; l < sizeof(placeholder); l++)`: `sizeof(placeholder)` is `225*225`, so `l` will be `50624` in the last iteration, which is out of bounds access at `placeholder[0][l]`.

Comment: oh you meant the printf(1) that is needed for my main func. and it does work in XV6 envionment as I indicated on the question. I get that the size of loop is wrong but even when I am just printing out placeholder[0][0] without running a loop - I still get the same message.

Comment: @mch: the xv6 `printf` definition is here: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public/blob/308a3b88c9e59b9065f1af9cdd2e0369cdfd0823/printf.c

Comment: And instead of `printf(1, "placeholder[0]%s: %c \n", l, placeholder[0][l]);`, I think it should be printf(1, "placeholder[0]%d: %c \n", l, placeholder[0][l]);